# How to retrieve base class only (entity framework)?

Tags: entity-framework

I've been scratching my head here for a while now...
I have a Consumer class and a BillableConsumer class that inherits Consumer. They are both a part of the Consumers set. The problem is that this following query:

```
Consumer consumer = (from c in _ctx.Consumers where c.ID = id select c).First();
```

returns a BillableConsumer instance! Just the same as this query:

```
BillableConsumer bconsumer = (from c in _ctx.Consumers.OfType<BillableConsumer>() where c.ID = id select c).First();
```

How can I return an instance of just the base class? (these are separate tables in the data store).

Comment: I guess trying to do this is a violation of Liskov substitution principle (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)
May be BillableConsumer is not kind of Consumer and you should make ConsumerBase with common fields and two inheritors: Consumer and BillableConsumer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is a little tricky.

But I did a [tip](http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2009/09/17/tip-35-how-to-write-oftypeonly-tentity.aspx) on this a while back

Hope this helps

Alex

Comment: for completeness, I would suggest posting the code sample in your answer, and point to your own blog for more information.